# How to write my own clone function

Tags: php, oop, clone

Every object-oriented language (or language which supports OOP), be it C++, Java, Python, PHP has a `clone` function of its own, which can return a deep or shallow copy of an object. Can anybody tell me how to create my own `clone` function from scratch, for both deep and shallow copy? Obviously I can't use any language-construct like `serialize`, not to mention `clone` itself! An example in `PHP` would be great, though any other language is fine as well, I need to know how to do it, that's all.

Comment: Reflections might be of interest to you.

Comment: Just a request, please think a bit before hurrying to downvote with all eagerness. I am a professional, doing a job in IBM, that has nothing to do with coding, it's from sheer academic interest I am asking this question. I don't know how to write such a function, hence I couldn't provide any 'research' I have done. Stackoverflow is replete with questions like `What is recursion`, with multiple upvotes, because other people have found it useful, even though the question showed no trace of research. Will such a question merit a downvote?

Comment: I didn't ask for a `+1`. Contrary to many others, I don't go around scouting for points, or asking somebody explicitly to upvote my answer. Most of the points I earn, I give it generously as bounty to others. But when somebody downvotes an answer or question straight-away without bothering to discuss, I am pissed. If my question wasn't clear, and left you hanging, you could have asked for a clarification, I could have provided a rope to hang on to. Downvoting without discussing is akin to shouting yourself hoarse at somebody without bothering to explain why.

Comment: Actually attempting something [Work In progress](http://pastebin.com/9phFhd3e) but your last response makes me think its just a waste of time good luck trying to prove your points ... NB: up votes or accepts are not dollars they are just a ways encourage and appreciate others if `somebody explicitly to upvote my answer` they only appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Part 1

```
/* memcpy example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
  char name[40];
  int age;
} person, person_copy;

int main ()
{
  char myname[] = "Pierre de Fermat";

  /* using memcpy to copy string: */
  memcpy ( person.name, myname, strlen(myname)+1 );
  person.age = 46;

  /* using memcpy to copy structure: */
  memcpy ( &person_copy, &person, sizeof(person) );

  printf ("person_copy: %s, %d \n", person_copy.name, person_copy.age );

  return 0;
}
```

taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/

### Part 2

[image: 1]

I'm assuming you need to copy all child elements of complicated objects(as in copying imaginary object A in figure 1,the code I've linked above can be used if you need only to copy the black color object but keeping others as references , the below pseudo code is for if you want to copy its all child items as well)
Above figures shows how the reality and how we think of an object

```
function MyCloneRecursive(object A) : object
{
    pointer Cpy;
    allocate memory to Cpy;
    memcpy(&Cpy,&A,sizeof(A))
    //now copy all its child elements
    //assuming there is a way to do a foreach that
    //for object A there are A.B,A.C and inside A.B there is D
    //and childname={"B","C"} and inside of B childname={"D"}
    for each childname in object A 
    {
        eval("Cpy." + childname + "=MyCloneRecursive(A." + childname + ")");
    }
}

//note this is really bad programming 
//clone function is better written in the runtime
//(or its a part of the intepreter not a includable code)
```

Comment: Can this be extended to clone complex objects as well? This, as I understand, is a rather simple object.

Comment: Isn't this question tagged as PHP?

Comment: yes all you have to do is copy the internal referenced structures by implementing a recursive copy memory function based on memcpy(there may be similar methods to memcpy in other languages as well)
btw,
@Claudrian: it says "though any other language is fine as well"

Comment: @Claudrian, Yes, it s tagged as `PHP`, but I said that any other language is fine too, I just wanna know how to do it.

Comment: @JaDogg, can you give an example of the recursive copy memory function? I am kind of weak in `C`.

Comment: Why is clone function is better written in the runtime
?

Comment: a) eval is bad,and slower


b) interpreter may have a better way to clone because interpreter can be programmed to get child elements of a given object,by parsing the code/tokens again


c)even in c memcpy() is a runtime function (based on my freeBASIC knowledge,not sure)

Answer (score 1):

I'll cover PHP here:

```
// Bad class
class Obj{
    private $_Property = 'value';
    public function __construct(){
        if(!func_num_args()){
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Needs arguments.');
        }
    }
}
// Instantiate
$obj = new Obj(1);
// Clone
$obj1 = clone $obj;
// Deep clone
$obj2 = unserialize(serialize($obj));
// Dump all (see it worked)
var_dump($obj);
var_dump($obj1);
var_dump($obj2);
// Now try to clone yourself
$objclass = get_class($obj);
// But you don't know the arguments for every class.
// And drama unfolds here, exceptions get thrown!
$obj3 = new $objclass();
```

**PHP clone $obj; and unserialize(serialize($obj)); elude the __construct()-or**. This way you get a baked object without putting it in the oven. To clone yourself, you need to put it in the oven (new-ing it). But you don't know the arguments for every objects and the __construct-or might break on you!

*Don't reinvent the core language wheel. You pretty much can't!*

**PS**: *There are also objects that can't be cloned.* SimpleXMLElement comes to my mind right now. You need to reparse this one with simplexml_load_string($sxe->asXML()) or import to DOM node and back to SXE.

Comment: Well, this uses `serialize`. Can't I create a clone with only basic stuff, like the C++ solution above does?

Comment: @Cupidvogel If you can READ my text and the code comments you'll get it (I hope). Otherwise... keep trying. Let me know when you succeed for non-basic objects.

Comment: Yes, I can READ your text, that's what I am asking. I asked how to write my own `clone` function, you are giving an example using the in-built `clone` function. I don't want to reinvent the core language wheel, but it's a common interview question, so I guess it's pretty much do-able without reinventing wheel. Yeah, may be it's not possible in `PHP`, I concede.

Comment: @Cupidvogel QUOTE: PHP clone $obj; and unserialize(serialize($obj)); elude the __construct()-or === as in YOU CAN'T! ... for any object that needs __construct() with arguments to work. I've made it bold so you don't miss it.